# Unpickling model in Google Colab; Received a value_error that dense_50 did not receive the expected variables

Tags: python, neural-network, google-colaboratory, valueerror, keras-layer

I have trained a neural network in Spyder, and it runs wonderfully. In order to make it faster I'm trying to test using GPUs, which is why I switched to Colab. When it unpickles my model, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Layer 'dense_50' expected 2 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['dense_50/kernel:0', 'dense_50/bias:0']
```

I did a quick search and it seems like adding ".legacy" to the keras layer imports would work, except that that's all in the pickle file so I'm not sure how to do that without retraining my model again.
My model has an input of a 3*8 matrix, which is then flattened and passed to a 32 node Dense layer, and then to an 8 node Dense layer with a Sigmoid activation.
In case it's relevant, I mounted my Goggle Drive in order to access the pickle file. Here's how I am importing the model:

```
DATA_PATH ="/content/drive/MyDrive/Matt/Codes/FlowshopProblemCode_rev3"
infile = open(DATA_PATH+'/singleMachineModel.pickle','rb')
model = pickle.load(infile)
```

Edit: Error text and code for model importing included.

Comment: please include your error as _text_ so it can be searched, copy-and-pasted, and discovered!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to chatGPT pickling doesn't save the variables as well. Using the built in keras save & load saves the weights & bias in a way that can be retrieved properly. I'm not sure why it worked in Spyder and not Google colab, but using the built in methods to save & load as a h5 file fixed the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).